# Android Activity Transition does not work with custom animations

Tags: android, android-transitions

I can't figure out why overridePendingTransition won't work with custom animtions.

**In MainActivity:**

```
private void goToDetails() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(requireContext(), DetailsActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**In DetailsActivity**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

The above code works as expected.  BUT, if I copy the source files from android.R.anim.slide_in_left & slide_out_right, then change this line to:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.my_slide_in_left, R.anim.my_slide_out_right);
```

Then the animation doesn't work - the default slide up animation happens.  I didn't change the code in the layout files, I literally copy/pasted them so I could tweak them later.

**/res/anim/my_slide_in_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-50%p" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

**/res/anim/my_slide_out_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="50%p"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

Comment: I have just maked the same in own project. Everything works fine with `my_slide_out_right` and `my_slide_in_left`. Try to clear and rebuild project

Comment: I just tried the same thing - brand new project (Nav Drawer activity), added a button to home fragment, added blank activity, then added the animations the same as my original code - and got the same result. The animations just won't work! Also: compileSdk = 30, minSdk = 25, targetSdk = 30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MainActivity click event:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), NewReportActivity.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

DetailActivity onBackPressed:

```
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

Comment: Thank you! Moving the overridePendingTransition to the MainActivity click event solved it